# Powers of compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Consider a Hilbert space $H$ and a compact self-adjoint operator $T : H \to H$. I want to prove that all positive powers (especially fractional powers) of $T$ are compact. From the spectral theorem, I see that powers of bounded operators are bounded. But I am unsure how to prove the corresponding statement for compact operators.

Comment: Compact $\times$ bounded $=$ compact.

Comment: For integer powers: it is almost as easy, and much more instructive, to prove that if T is compact then so are RT and TS for any bounded operators R and S.

Comment: In your setting, diagonalize, and then try to prove every diagonal matrix with c_0 entries is compact.

Answer (score 3):

Using the spectral theorem: A selfadjoint operator $T \ne 0$ on a Hilbert space is compact iff
$$
                   T = \lambda_1 E_{1} + \lambda_2 E_{2} + \cdots,
$$
where $\{ E_{j} \}$ is a finite or countably infinite set of disjoint orthogonal projections onto finite-dimensional subspaces, and the sequence $\{ \lambda_{j} \}$, if infinite, converges to $0$. (The convergence of the sum, if infinite, is in the strong operator topology.)

With that spectral characterization, you can see that powers of $T$ are compact:
$$
                  T^{\alpha} =\lambda_1^{\alpha}E_{1}+\lambda_2^{\alpha}E_{2}+\cdots.
$$

Comment: If the compact operator is not positive, I think that the fractional powers might be ill-defined

Comment: @SergioA.Yuhjtman : Pick a branch. You can define $T^{\alpha}$. The properties of the resulting $T^{\alpha}$ may not be what you want, but it's defined if you choose a branch of $z^{\alpha}$. And, the resulting $T^{\alpha}$ is compact.